# tab bar cant not display a full text

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I drag and drop a a tab bar from xcode like this
[image]

However, when I run the application... I am getting

[image]

Does any one know why my tab bat can not display a full text... Please advice me on this issue. Thanks

Comment: Where is that little arrow above the selected tab coming from?  Also, the text for the tab bar is bigger than usual.  Are you using custom code to create the tab bar?

Comment: no I am not. Like i indicated in the OP, I drag and drop from the xcode. Dont worry about the arrow. It does not affect to tab bar at all. I try to remove but still can not display a full text in tab bar

Comment: The label for the tab bar title is definitely bigger than it should be, which I think is contributing to it becoming abbreviated.  Trying to think why that would be happening with all components right out of IB...

Comment: Can you post the code from viewDidLoad of detail controller?

Comment: hey I found out my issue. The reason is I did change the font somehow thru my application. Any way, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are manually changing the font of the label. Find where you are changing it, and correct the label dimensions.